# How to find an equation of this 3D-straight line?

Tags: geometry

For didactic purposes I'd like to find an equation of the 3D-straight line passing through the origin
and intersecting both 3D-straight lines $\{x-y+z-2=0, x-2 y+3 z-8=0\}$ and
$\{y - z + 1 = 0 , x + y - 2 z + 4 = 0\}$.

I do it in such a way.

```
p1 = FindInstance[x - y + z - 2 == 0 && x - 2 y + 3 z - 8 == 0, {x, y, z}, Reals, 2];
L1 = InfiniteLine[Table[{x, y, z} /. p1[[j]], {j, 1, 2}]];
p2 = FindInstance[y - z + 1 == 0 && x + y - 2 z + 4 == 0, {x, y, z},Reals, 2];
L2 = InfiniteLine[Table[{x, y, z} /. p2[[j]], {j, 1, 2}]];
```

Now

```
Resolve[Exists[t, {a*t, b*t, c*t} \[Element] L1] && 
Exists[s, {a*s, b*s, c*s} \[Element] L2], Reals]
```

> `a - b != 0 && a - c != 0 && 3 a - 2 b + c == 0 && a - 3 b + 2 c == 0`

```
FindInstance[a - b != 0 && a - c != 0 && 3 a - 2 b + c == 0 && 
a - 3 b + 2 c == 0, {a, b, c},Reals]
```

> `{{a -> 1, b -> 5, c -> 7}}`

Therefore, the requested line is `InfiniteLine[{0,0,0},{1,5,7}]` and its parametric equations are `{t,5*t,7*t}`.

Is there a simpler and shorter way to do the job
(The usage of a long formula from a thick handbook on analytical geometry is not allowed.)?

Comment: It should be noticed the above approach works if the given two lines are parallel (Then the solution may not exist and `FindInstance` in the latest command results in `{}`,) and the  given two lines intersect. One may try `p1 = FindInstance[x - 2 == 0 && 3 z - 8 == 0, {x, y, z}, Reals, 2];p2 = FindInstance[x - 3 == 0 && 3 z - 8 == 0, {x, y, z}, Reals, 2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we can solve for a parametric version of the first line

```
 l1 = ({x, y, z} /. Solve[{x - 2 == 0, 3 z - 8 == 0}, {x, y, z}] // First) /. {x -> s, y -> s, z -> s}
 (*   {2, s, 8/3}  *)
```

and the second line...

```
 l2 = ({x, y, z} /.Solve[{y - z + 1 == 0, x + y - 2 z + 4 == 0}, {x, y, z}] //  First) /. {x -> t, y -> t, z -> t}
 (*   {t, 2 + t, 3 + t}   *)
```

You also can potentially get a warning you can ignore...

```
  "Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables."
```

Then find the values of $s$ and $t$ such that $l1(s)$ is in line with $l2(t)$ from the origin.

```
  res = Solve[l1 == α l2, {α, s, t}] // First 

 (*   {α -> 2/9, s -> 22/9, t -> 9}   *)
```

Your line is then parameterized as...

```
 (l1 /. res) u
 (*   {2u, (22u)/9, (8u)/3}   *)
```

Comment: Something to adjust: `res` in last but one line is not defined. Also `(l1 /. res)t` is not grounded. Thank you anyway.

Comment: A more serious remark: your approach does not work for some lines, e.g. `{x, y, z} /. Solve[{x - 2 == 0, 3 z - 8 == 0}, {y, z}] // First` results in `x`,whereas the approach used by me works. It is not so simple.

Comment: In addition to the above: `FindInstance[{x - 2 == 0, 3 z - 8 == 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals, 2]` results in `{{x -> 2, y -> 1/2, z -> 8/3}, {x -> 2, y -> 3/5, z -> 8/3}}`.

Comment: I will be waiting for more qualified answers. Thank you again and again.

Comment: Yeah, it's not global, but the main idea of parameterizing the two lines then solving for those parameters and the scaling α holds. Best of luck!

Comment: It is difficult to realize  that idea programmatically.

Comment: +1. After analyzing your answer, I find your approach the best of the three ones. I may suggest an improvement: to find parametric equations of the given lines by `FindInstance` as I do it. If you do it, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I've made an edit which seems to deal with all cases. It parameterizes the lines successfully even if some dimensions are fixed (line parallel to an axis).

Comment: I'm always a little wary of `FindInstance` because you can get a different result than from `Solve`. Compare `FindInstance[{x - 2 == 0, 3 z - 8 == 0}, {x, y, z}]` to `Solve[{x - 2 == 0, 3 z - 8 == 0}, {x, y, z}]`.

Comment: Can you explain what ` {x -> s, y -> s, z -> s}` in line 2 does? TIA.

Comment: I got it on my own: this substitution gives a parametrization for variables absent in `Solve`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use implicit equations (as linear polynomials), with separate variables for each line. Augment with equations to force the vector from a point on one line to the origin, to be parallel to a vector from point on the other line to the origin. This gives equations that determine the two intersecting points. Augment further by having the vector from a point on the new line to one of these be parallel to the vector between same point on the new line and the other. These involve using two new variables to account for vectors being scalar multiples of one another. Last, compute a Groebner basis and eliminate all unwanted variables.

```
vars1 = {x1, y1, z1};
vars2 = {x2, y2, z2};
vars = {x, y, z};
polys = Flatten[{vars1 . {1, -1, 1} - 2, vars1 . {1, -2, 3} - 8, 
    vars2 . {0, 1, -1} + 1, vars2 . {1, 1, -2} + 4, 
    vars1 - s*vars2, (vars - vars1) - t*(vars - vars2)}];
GroebnerBasis[polys, vars, Join[vars1, vars2, {s, t}]]

(* Out[2270]= {7 y - 5 z, 7 x - z} *)
```

Comment: -1. The above is done rather by hand. Is that approach understandable  for students? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Does your approach work  if two given lines intersect?

Comment: @user64494 Words fail me. (Well, not really, I'm just not willing to put them into an MSE comment.) In any case this is the last response to any MSE question you will get from me. Your wackiness has finally exceeded my capacity.

Comment: DanielLichblau (@does not work): I  cancel my  "-1".

Comment: Thank you. It is generally not good forum practice to punish people who offer assistance, even when they miss the mark. (Better to let other people punish them for that.)

Comment: PS It was actually -2. Don't ask me why. Maybe because it comes from the original poster?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

```
sol=FindInstance[
 t1*{x, y, z} ∈ 
   ImplicitRegion[
    x - y + z - 2 == 0 && x - 2 y + 3 z - 8 == 0, {x, y, z}] && 
  t2*{x, y, z} ∈ 
   ImplicitRegion[
    y - z + 1 == 0 && x + y - 2 z + 4 == 0, {x, y, z}], {t1, t2, x, y,
   z}, Reals]
{x, y, z} /. sol
```

> `{{-1, -5, -7}}`

**Original**

```
reg1 = ParametricRegion[{t*{x, y, z}, 
    x - y + z - 2 == 0 && x - 2 y + 3 z - 8 == 0}, {x, y, z, t}];
reg2 = ParametricRegion[{t*{x, y, z}, 
    y - z + 1 == 0 && x + y - 2 z + 4 == 0}, {x, y, z, t}];
reg = RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2];
Simplify[RegionMember[reg][{x, y, z}], {x, y, z} ∈ Reals]
FindInstance[{x, y, z} ∈ reg, {x, y, z}, 1]
FindInstance[{x, y, z} ∈ reg, {x, y, z}, 2]
```

> `(x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0) || (3 x + z == 2 y &&  x + 2 z ==  3 y && (((2 x != y || x + 3 z != 2 y) && x != y) || x != z))`

> `{{x -> 1/2, y -> 5/2, z -> 7/2}, {x -> 3/5, y -> 3, z -> 21/5}}`

```
Show[Region[reg1, BaseStyle -> Cyan], 
 Region[reg2, BaseStyle -> Yellow], 
 Region[reg, BaseStyle -> {Thick, Red}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't find it simpler than mine. You consider parametric regions in four dimensions. However, a fresh approach.+1.

Comment: Nice solution approach